# OData can not expand Many-to-Many

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I can't expand nested table. Here is the example:

**File**:

```
    public class File 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<FileFileStatus> FileFileStatuses { get; set; }
}
```

**FileFileStatus**:

```
public class FileFileStatus
{
    public Guid FileId { get; set; }

    public File File { get; set; }

    public Guid FileStatusId { get; set; }

    public FileStatus FileStatus { get; set; }
}
```

**FileStatus**:

```
    public class FileStatus
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<FileFileStatus> FileFileStatuses { get; set; }
}
```

**ModelConfiguration**:

```
        var files = builder.EntitySet<File>("Files").EntityType;
        files.HasMany(f => f.FileFileStatus);

        var fileFileStatuses = builder.EntityType<FileFileStatus>().HasKey(f => new { f.FileStatusId, f.FileId });
        fileFileStatuses.HasRequired(f => f.FileStatus);

        builder.EntityType<FileStatus>().HasKey(f => f.Id);
```

And here is how I am trying to get result:

https://localhost:44335/odata/Files?$top=10&$expand=FileFileStatuses

I am recieving empty FileFileStatuses

Comment: I can't find the reason from the models. It's same as me. Does https://localhost:44335/odata/Files?$top=10 return Files data?

Answer (score 0):

It works on me.

**Expand**
[image]

**Without Expand**
[image]

> Codes of Models

```
public class File
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<FileFileStatus> FileFileStatuses { get; set; }
}

public class FileFileStatus
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid FileId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FileId")]
    public File File { get; set; }

    public Guid FileStatusId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FileStatusId")]
    public FileStatus FileStatus { get; set; }
}

public class FileStatus
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<FileFileStatus> FileFileStatuses { get; set; }
}
```

> Codes of Controller

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("Files")]
public class FilesController : ODataController
{
    private readonly XxxDbContext xxxDbContext;
    public FilesController(XxxDbContext xxxDbContext)
            => this.xxxDbContext = xxxDbContext;


    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok(this.xxxDbContext.Files);
    }

}
```

> Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        services.AddOData();
        services.AddDbContext<XxxDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("XxxDbContext")));

    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "odata/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
            endpoints.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(10);

        });

    }
```